# Specific VCS branch unavailable to choose in manual build run

Tags: teamcity, teamcity-9.1

I have a Build Configuration connected to VCS Root. In VCS I have branches `feature-123`, `feature-234`, `feature-345`, etc.

If I go to Build Configuration Overview and choose [Run...] -> Changes -> Build Branch, dropdown shows `feature-123`, `feature-345`. (Note `feature-234` is not in the list).

Build Configuration has a VCS trigger with branch filter `+:*`. Trigger reacts to changes in all branches, including `feature-234`, so I know TC can see it.

What I can't figure out is why can't I chose to build from `feature-234` manually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I identified few cases which can cause this, and solutions.

1. The branch just has been pushed on your server, and has not been fetched by TeamCity. Just wait a few minutes.
2. The branch might be considered as inactive, there is the property: `teamcity.activeVcsBranch.age.days` which can be modified, with the default value of `7`. If there was no commits on it, in the last 7 days, the branch will not be visible in your active branches, and will not be able to see it in the drop down list.

   2.a : You can increase the timer.

   2.b : Adding a dummy commit on this branch will make it visible again.
3. In few exceptional cases, I was not able to find a branch in the dropdown, but, when I select a specific build configuration, It seems that more inactives branches are available, then I run a build on it, and it will be available inside the containing project.

Comment: The branch is definitely active as it was minutes after TC picked up a commit in it and built it. It still did not appear in the dropdown. Branch is new, but not minutes-old-new. Maybe it takes TC longer to update those dropdowns than I'd think. I'll check if it's there on Monday.